# RX: How to bind an IObservable<object> to a property (ReactiveUI)

Tags: c#, wpf, observable, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have class `MyClient` with an `IObservable<IStatus>` (`Client.StatusStream()`). Now I would like to combine `ReactiveX` and `ReactiveUI`. But the documentation is not providing any example how to use them together.

I have tried some extension methods so far (f.e. `.ToProperty`), but they are not working.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<AppViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = App.Container.GetInstance<AppViewModel>();
        this.WhenActivated(r =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Status.AoiStatus, view => view.StatusTxtbl.Text).DisposeWith(r);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Status.OperationMode, view => view.OpModeTxtbl.Text).DisposeWith(r);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Status.TestPlan, view => view.TestplanTxtbl.Text).DisposeWith(r);
            });
    }

    private async void ButtonGetStatus_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // the manual mode to get the actual status information
        var status = await ViewModel.Client.GetStatusAsync();
        ViewModel.Status = status;
    }
}

public class AppViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private IStatus _Status;
    public IStatus Status
    {
        get => _Status;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Status, value);
    }

    public MyClient Client { get; }

    public AppViewModel(MyClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
        // automatically pushes every new status information
        Client.StatusStream(); // <- How to get the data out there?
    }
}
```

### Info

To notify the gui about new updates, to have to use `ObserveOnDispatcher`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55811495/6229375

Comment: If you go with ToProperty it’s just _status = Client.StatusStream().ToProperty(this, x => x.Status). ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IStatus> _status; public IStatus Status => _status.Value;

Comment: Thanks for your comment and also working solution. But now my properties are not updated anymore. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `Status` as an [output property](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/):

```
public class AppViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IStatus> _status;
    public string Status => _status.Value;

    public MyClient Client { get; }

    public AppViewModel(MyClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
        Client.StatusStream().ToProperty(this, x => x.Status, out _status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that work's so far. But now the properties are not automatically updated anymore. Do I have to change my `OneWayBind` syntax in the constructor of the `MainWindow`?