# RX: 'ObservableAsProperty' bound properties are not automatically updated on gui

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have a Client `MyClient` which provides new stati via an `IObservable`. As described in the documentation (https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/boilerplate-code) I made a private property of type `ObservableAsProperty` to get the output of my `IObservable`. But know my GUI is not updated automatically on changes.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<AppViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = App.Container.GetInstance<AppViewModel>();
        this.WhenActivated(r =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Status.AoiStatus, view => view.StatusTxtbl.Text).DisposeWith(r);
            });
    }
}

public class AppViewModel : ReactiveObject
{

    public IStatus Status { [ObservableAsProperty] get; }

    public MyClient Client { get; }

    public AppViewModel(MyClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
        Client.StatusStream().ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Status);
    }
}

public interface IStatus
{
    string AoiStatus { get; }
}
```

If I bind the gui via `xaml` with my `DataContext`, everything works as expected. `ViewModel.PropertyChanged` is fired, so I don't know what's wrong there?!

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<AppViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = App.Container.GetInstance<AppViewModel>();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class AppViewModel : ReactiveObject
{

    public IStatus Status { [ObservableAsProperty] get; }

    public MyClient Client { get; }

    public AppViewModel(MyClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
        Client.StatusStream().ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Status);
    }
}

public interface IStatus
{
    string AoiStatus { get; }
}
```

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Status:" />
    <Run Text="{Binding ViewModel.Status.AoiStatus, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I can't comment yet, so I'll paste it here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553471/1829812.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work if you observe the stream on the dispatcher thread:

```
public AppViewModel(MyClient client)
{
    Client = client;
    Client.StatusStream().ObserveOnDispatcher().ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Status);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!  But could you explain why I have to `ObserveOnDispatcher`? If I don't use it, the property is also set, the`propertyChangedEvent` is raised and `xaml` is working as expected. I'm confused..

Comment: @DominicJonas: Yes, but the `OneWayBind` throws when it tries to apply the binding to the `TextBlock` from a background thread.